# Raising an event in a Task causes the subscriber method to fail

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task, threadpool

I have a few classes that are "linked" via various events. Basically a `TCPListener`, `ClientSession` and `Server`.

The `TCPListener` bubbles new connections up to the `Server` and then the `Server` creates a new `ClientSession`.

`TCPListener` passes the new socket via an event, `ClientConnected`.

The method raising the event looks like this:

```
    //Processes a new connection and immediately puts the listen socket back in a receiving state
    private void ProcessAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        ClientConnected(this, e));            

        StartAccept();
    }
```

I wanted to avoid doing anything that could prevent or slow down the accepting of new clients so I endeavored to raise the event with a Task. The reason for this is a user can override the `OnClientConnected` method in `Server` such that it is long running and could impact server performance.

Here is the revised method:

```
    //Processes a new connection and immediately puts the listen socket back in a receiving state
    private void ProcessAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() => ClientConnected(this, e));            

        StartAccept();
    }
```

When the program is run with the new method, there are no exceptions on crashes, yet the server is unable to receive or send to the client.

Here is the `OnClientConnected` method in `Server`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// An event that is fired when a client connects.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The Listener that accepted the connection</param>
    /// <param name="e">The SocketAsyncEventArgs </param>
    protected virtual void OnClientConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientSession Session = ClientSessionPool.Pop();

        Session.Socket = ((SocketAsyncEventArgs)e).AcceptSocket;

        string WelcomeMessage = "Connected";

        Session.SendAsync(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(WelcomeMessage));

        this.ClientSessions.Add(Session);

        Console.Write($"\rConnected clients:{ClientSessions.Count}");
    }
```

Simply reverting back to the old, synchronous method works just fine.

<del>What is bugging me is that the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` that is passed through the event seems to be correct regardless of using `Task` or not and that is the only point of failure I can think of.</del>

The `SocketAsyncEventArgs` seems to be completely wrong when using the `Task` version of the method.

I suspect it is my understanding of the stack allocated to a new thread that is causing my confusion. Can anyone see a hole in my logic? Thanks!

**PS**

I am aware that my current implementation of the `ClientSessions` list is NOT thread safe, but in my testing, I am only ever connecting with one client at a time. I *will* eventually fix that.

**PPS**
Here  is the `StartAccept` method in case it is useful:

```
    //Puts the accepting TCP socket back into an accepting state
    public void StartAccept()
    {
        // socket must be cleared since the context object is being reused
        m_SocketEventArgs.AcceptSocket = null;

        bool willRaiseEvent = m_Socket.AcceptAsync(m_SocketEventArgs);
        if (!willRaiseEvent)
        {
            ProcessAccept(m_SocketEventArgs);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you not just racing with StartAccept?

Comment: @dlatikay Don't think so. `StartAccept` doesn't touch anything that `ClientConnected` does asides from the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` but even that is copied to the new `Task`'s stack (I think). I'll add `StartAccept` to the question, let me know.

Comment: @dlatikay OH SNAP! I see it now... `m_SocketEventArgs.AcceptSocket = null;`... That's it, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On solution would be to raise your event on the UI thread but run your event handling asynchronously.

```
private async void OnClientConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => HandleClientConnected(object, e));
}

protected abstract Task HandleClientConnected(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Comment: Not sure if a console program still counts as having a "UI" thread. I Don't quite understand what this would achieve... Wouldn't this just block until the `Task` is finished essentially making this method synchronous and non-parallel?

Comment: @Connel.O'Donnell I think I see. Does it just await the *creation* of the task and *not* the execution of it?

Comment: Exactly. Or you could just treat the handler as a fire-and-forget command by not awaiting it.

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure I understand... Do you mean to keep the method as `async` but omit the `await`? If that's the case, it would be ideal, I don't care for the result of the task at all :)